# Choosing the right analysis for DAG - Which quasi-experimental alternative to instrumental variables?

Tags: causality, research-design

I am writing a statistical analysis plan for a project but I am having difficulties finding the best analysis to answer my question.

I am working with the conceptual framework below:

- There is likely a direct effect of Genetics with Disease (green pathway)
- The role of Exposure in relation with Genetics is less clear and there are several hypothesis.

  1. Exposure is a mediator of the effect of Genetics on Disease (blue pathway)
  2. Exposure has a direct effect on Disease regardless of Genetics (red pathway)
  3. Both are true

The data has been collected in a longitudinal study. All of these (+ some potential confounders) have been documented.

This framework looked like a situation for using an instrumental variable to me. I identified a risk factor of exposure that is not linked with Genetics and Disease that could be used as such.

My problem is that my main research question is to identify if there is a direct effect of Exposure on Disease. From what I understand of mediation analysis, it would explain the nature of the link between Genetics and Disease (through Exposure or not). Still because I deal with causal implications, I would prefer a quasi-experimental analysis.

What would be the best way to show the  (non-)existence of a direct link between Exposure and Disease, independently from the effects of Genetics?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how the blue vs red arrows from Exposure to Disease are meant to be different? Is it some shorthand you're using for representing two different DAG structures?

Comment: Yes, kind of. I know it is not standard notation but here red represent a causal independent effect from exposure on disease (my main research interest). The blue path represent a causal effect of genetics, mediated through exposure. So that the red is the effect that would be left if I could completely adjust for genetics. In practice this would be difficult to do due to other variables related to both. This is the main reason why I am looking for a quasi experimental experimental analyses.